How to find general solution to differential equation given a particular solution
Given $y=sinx$ is a solution of the ODE:
$y^{\prime}=\frac{2cos^2x-sin^2x+y^2}{2cosx}$
How can I find the general solution to the equation?
It seems as if there exists some form of a generalised approach to exercises of this nature and so, if possible, I would most appreciate an explanation or a reference to where it might be found.

The ode is not linear so the linear techniques are not applicable.

Consider the transform $y(x)=u(x)+\sin x$, it yields $u'=\frac{u^2+2u\sin x}{2\cos x}$. This is a Bernoulli's ODE.

As @GuyangHuan wrote in comments, let $y=u +\sin(x)$ and then $u=\frac 1 v$ to make
$$v'+\tan(x)\,v=-\frac 12\sec (x)$$ which is very simple (use the variation of the parameter).

The method is called 'Variation of the Constant'. Set $$y(x) =( h(x) +1) \sin x.$$ This ansatz yields a nonlinear equation in $h$
$$h' = \ \frac{1}{2} \left(h^2 \tan (x)\ - \ 2 \ h \ \frac{ \cos (2 x)}{\sin (x)\ \cos(x)} \right)$$
one of the Ricatti equations
